# Javascript/JQuery time counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im looking for :

count time - in seconds & minutes. 
my count i want it start when one button is clicked and stop if clicked again. 
my counting from zero for every button when clicked.

here is what i tried but it seems not working.

```
function toggle(ths) {
    $(ths).toggleClass("btnColor");
    $("#tb").toggleClass("btnColorR")
    var secondCounter = 0;
    var minutes = 0;
    var t;
    var timer_is_on = 0;
    var clicked = $(ths).val();
    secondCounter = secondCounter + 1;
    if ((secondCounter % 60 == 0 )&&(clicked)) {
        minutes += 1;
        secondCounter = 0;
    }
    $("#setCount").html(" downtime type: " + clicked + " minutes: " + minutes + "     seconds: " + secondCounter);
}
```

Comment: i cant see a loop where you keep incrementing your 'secondCounter' until the user clicks on the button 'again'

Answer (score 1):

Question would be clear if you post html code which is calling that `toggle()` function.

My guess is `minutes` and `secondCounter` are resetting to 0 every time `toggle()` function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need a way to find the time elapsed between two clicks on the button

Also assuming that on the second click you want to know the time it took since the last time it was clicked and reset the counter

If so I have a simple jsfiddle that you can look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/8cjBj/

HTML CODE:

```
<a href="#" id="btn">This is a button</a>
```

JS CODE:

```
var start = 0;
var end = 0;

$('#btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if(start == 0)
        start = new Date();
    else
    {
        end = new Date();
        millis = end - start;
        var totalSeconds = parseInt(millis / 1000);
        var minutes = parseInt(totalSeconds / 60);
        var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        alert('Elapsed Time: ' + minutes + ' Minutes and ' + seconds + ' seconds');
        start = 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks a lot man ,im really new to this ,my last question how can i show the TIME incrementing on web page if clicked for the first time and when clicked for the second time it must show elapse time as it doing

Comment: i want to see the COUNT incrementing ( 5h:18m:56s) on web page not only to increment behind the scene  ,im sorry to bother

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how much time button was toggled down, you can try this code:

```
var displayElapsedTime,
    startTimeCounter,
    isDown;

isDown = function isDown($this) {
  return $this.is('.down');
};

displayElapsedTime = function displayElapsedTime($this) {
  var time = new Date((new Date()) - $this.data('time'));
  $this.val(time.getMinutes() + ':' + time.getSeconds());
};

startTimeCounter = function startTimeCounter($this) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    displayElapsedTime($this);
    if(isDown($this)) {
      startTimeCounter($this);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

$('input').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if(!isDown($this)) {
    $this.data('time', new Date());
    startTimeCounter($this);
  }

  $this.toggleClass('down');
});
```

You can see working example here: http://jsbin.com/ahafez/3/edit

Comment: thanks a lot man ,im really new to this ,my last question how can i show the TIME incrementing on web page if clicked for the first time and when clicked for the second time it must show elapse time as it doing

Comment: @C_Major I have added functionality you requested: now elapsed time is displayed on the button. Link with example is also updated.

Comment: wow ! great Job man main problem was to terninate it ,thanks again it work perfectly